# How do different communities practice regarding women's saying a b'racha on s'firas haomer?

Tags: blessing, women, ashkenazi, sefirat-ha-omer, communities

[*Mishna B'rura* 489:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=189) says women do not say a *b'racha* on *s'firas haomer*; [*Aruch Hashulchan* 489:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A4.D7.98_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93) says they do. What is the practice of various *Ashk'nazi* communities (for example, chassidic (various sects), "yeshivish" (various *yeshivos*), German, Dutch, and so on)?

Comment: Very similar later question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57013

Answer (score 2):

In Norvadahk the woman say with a Bracha.

By Chasidim that come from Sanz (Klausanberg, Bobov) the woman do not say or say without a Bracha.

Comment: "In Norvadahk the woman say with a Bracha" - That would explain the Aruch Hashulchan's _p'sak_, right?