# What kind of cleanliness is required to put on Tefillin?

Tags: women, tefilin

The [Rama says](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%97_%D7%92) (OC 38:3) that one must protest a woman's putting on Tefillin. The Magen Avraham there (sk 3) says that this is...:

> מפני שצריכין גוף נקי ונשים אינם זריזות להזהר...
>   ...because [Tefillin] require a clean body, and women aren't quick to be careful [about this].

What kind of cleanliness are we talking about? It's kind of hard to believe that women (even 400 years ago) would need to go to the bathroom uncontrollably.

Comment: I have a very adult and un-PC theory about this.

Answer (score 1):

The Aruch Hashulchan 38:6 writes that women are patur and if they want to we should protest because of the reason of having a clean body.He brings Elisha from the gemara in shabbas with the story of the Romans and his teffilin turning into kanfei yona ,the point was that Elisha was very careful in being clean while donning teffilin.One has to be in his state of cleanliness(breaking wind,falling asleep is forbidden).

So how can mean wear it they aren't any cleaner.So he answers men only wear it for prayer and we wear it because we are obligated but one who is exempt should not put themselves into a situation when it is very hard to be clean like Elisha.

He mentions that by Michal the chachamim did not protest because it was known she was a complete tzaddeikas and she was very careful.

Comment: The quoted Magen Avraham himself already brings the same point about overriding chiyuv. Can you elaborate on what defines "cleanliness"? Women then probably weren't falling asleep uncontrollably either.

Comment: @doubleaa yep , he writes at the end look at the Magen Avraham.

Comment: Clean like Elisha

Comment: I never met Elisha. In what ways was he so clean?

Comment: It seems (Lefi Anius Daatu) that "al pi peshat" a person just has to be clean enough not to sleep or pass gas.

Comment: And it doesn't say that women can't wear tefillin because "they can't pay attention to them". Just cleanliness.

Comment: @doubleaa the gemara says the two reasons I mentioned breaking wind and sleeping.Elisha was carful mashma others were not .its pashut pshat gemara see Tosfos maybe being motzei zera while sleeping.

Comment: @doubleaa I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: If it's just that, then frankly I don't see what is so hard about avoiding those things while wearing tefillin for an hour. Nor any reason why we shouldn't expect women to be able to handle that or even to expect they would have any difficulty at all. Nor why Elisha is all that impressive.

Comment: story of Elisha is in n Shabbas 130

Comment: @doubleaa so that's a separate question,but with regards to this q I think I answered it satisfactory and in a clear manner.

Comment: Possibly similar to this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6970/womens-saying-a-bracha-on-sfiras-haomer#comment65953_6970

Comment: Is the aruch talking about Elisha and Michal wearing tefillin for all day or just an hour? It is hard for anyone to maintain that cleanliness all day so the male chiyuv would be the only reason to wear them.  But if the current practice of just in davening is considered, it might not be that hard for anyone.

Comment: The chinuch 421 brings down some opinions about being clean from sin. Eye of the storm by Rav Aron Feldman brings down a concept of having pure thoughts as well. Those are much taller orders i think.