# Do women need to count the Omer?

Tags: halacha, women, sefirat-ha-omer

Is counting the Omer nowadays considered a time-bound Mitzva that women are exempt from?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6970

Answer (score 6):

R' C Cohen writes in [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/women-and-sefiras-haomer.html)

> .. There is another machlokes as to whether women are obligated at all. Ramban (Kiddushin 34a) holds that women are obligated, while Rambam (Temidin Umusafin 7:24; Sefer Hamitzvot 161) and the Magen Avraham (OC 489:1) hold that as it is a time-bound mitzva, women are exempt.
>
> The Mishna Berura (489:3) quotes the Shulchan Shlomo (489:3) who writes that as women will probably forget to count one night they shouldn’t count with a beracha at all. Nonetheless, the Aruch Hashulchan (OC 489:4) and R’ Ephraim Greenblatt (Rivevos Ephraim 1:327; 6:257:23) write that women do keep this mitzva nowadays and should count with a beracha. Especially as people set alarms nowadays to remind themselves of such things, women should do so, too.